# How do I use Django's ModelForm to set data in fields added by a ManyToManyField's through table?

Tags: python, django, forms

In `models.py`:

```
    ingredient_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(this):
        return this.ingredient_name

class Recipe(models.Model):
    recipe_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='RecipeIngredient')
    sales_price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(this):
        return this.recipe_name

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe_name = models.ForeignKey('Recipe', models.CASCADE)
    ingredient_name = models.ForeignKey('Ingredient', models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

In `forms.py`:

```
class RecipeFormCreate(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('recipe_name', 'ingredients', 'sales_price')
```

The created form looks like this:
[Form generated by RecipeFormCreate, with the "Ingredients" field having a list of items that can be selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58lR0.png)

Is there a way to allow the end user of this product to set the ingredient's quantity (a field added by the `RecipeIngredient` model) within the `RecipeFormCreate` form?

Comment: You use a `FormSet` for the `RecipeIngredient`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you elaborate with a code snippet? Using the formset directly only generates one form with no way to add more, nor will it let me submit even the one without creating another recipe.